# Access and edit .bashrc via ssh on terminal

Tags: xubuntu, ssh, bashrc

I try to access `.bashrc` by typing `~/.bashrc` on my terminal. I am connecting to a remote server via ssh. I get an access denied message. I have no problems logging in, just the access denied message for that file. I need to edit it to load a compiler. How do I do that? I have very recently started using Xubuntu and ssh, so I would appreciate an easy to follow answer.

Comment: What do you see when you type `ls -al ~/.bashrc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to load environmental variables from `.bashrc`, you can use

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

If for some reason you want to execute it, you have to change permissions first:

```
chmod u+x ~/.bashrc
```

After that, you can execute it with

```
~/.bashrc
```

However, it doesn't do that much, as it only initializes your shell options.

Answer (score 1):

`.bashrc` is a file, not a command. The syntax `~/.bashrc` attempts to run it as a script, which doesn't work. To edit it, you need to first write the name of an appropriate editor - `nano` is probably a good choice.

Edit the file with `nano ~/.bashrc` (save and exit with ctrl-x), then disconnect and reconnect to activate the changes.